# Mockito Spring 3.1 Integration

Tags: spring, mockito

I have been using @Configuration support in Spring to create my Mockito Mocks for use in JUnit tests

```
@Configuration
public class MockAppContextHelper {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationServerServiceWrapper integrationServerServiceWrapperTest() {
        return mock(IntegrationServerServiceWrapper.class);
    }

}
```

This used to work fine in Spring 3.0.2.

In Spring 3.1 I get the following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationServerServiceWrapperTest' defined in class path resource [com/kn/bpa/task/service/impl/MockAppContextHelper.class]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'mockAppContextHelper'; factory method 'integrationServerServiceWrapperTest()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your support

Comment: I have never built mock in that way (with @Configuration and @Bean) and I don't know what is the reason of your error, but you can take a look at project [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) which greatly simplify creating mocks in Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a reproduction project per the instructions at https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework-issues#readme that demonstrates the configuration in question working in 3.0.2 and failing against 3.1.x